# Does this character have limits as a mortal?

Tags: dragonlance

In the *Dragonlance* series, we learn that

> Fizban is Paladine

Does he have power limits as a mortal?

> Or does he maintain his godlike abilities?

Comment: Wouldn't he necessarily have to maintain his godlike abilities in order to turn back into Paladine?

Comment: Well, I doubt that stabbing him through the chest would work out the way you were hoping it would, if that's what you mean.

Comment: That character fell into a very deep pit, hit bottom leaving behind a susbstantial mess of chicken feathers, and show up later like nothing happened. If he has limits, they're not standard.

Answer (score 5):

At least in the 1st edition RPG version of Dragonlance, no, he had his full abilities.

Dragonlance Adventures, p. 108, "Personalities of the Age of Dragons", first sentence of the gray game-text box:

> Descriptions of Paladine and his statistics can be found in the
>   section on Krynn's gods

Given how closely the RPG material is linked to the original Dragonlance Chronicles trilogy, I think that is fairly solid evidence.